# Paged List in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

To perform paging I have followed this method
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Now what I am trying to do is change the page size by choosing a value from drop down

```
 Page Sige :
           @{
             IList<SelectListItem> pageSizeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
             pageSizeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5", Selected = true });
             pageSizeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
             pageSizeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "15", Value = "15" });
             pageSizeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "20", Value = "20" });
             pageSizeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
             }
             @Html.DropDownListFor(per => per.PageSize, pageSizeList, new
             {
                @onchange = "location.href='/AdminSearchResult/AdminSearchResult?pageSizeInput=' + this.value;"
             })
```

After choosing the value from dropdown I made few changes to my sorting and paging action links. I added a bool parameter isPageSort, as follows

```
@Html.ActionLink("  Previous Page  ", "AdminSearchResult", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, isSortPage = "true"  }) -------For paging

@Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "AdminSearchResult", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, isSortPage = "true" }) ------For sorting
```

based on this bool parameter I save the current page size in session and retrieve to maintain the page size in my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AdminSearchResult(string sortOrder, int? page, int pageSizeInput = 0,  bool isSortPage = false)
    {
        int pageSize = 5;         
        int pageNumber = 1;
        if (page != null)
            pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(page);


        if (!isSortPage)
        {
            if (pageSizeInput != 0)
                pageSize = pageSizeInput;
            Session["pageSize"] = pageSize;
        }
        else
            pageSize = (int)Session["pageSize"];

        Session["sortOrder"] = sortOrder;
        Session["pageNumber"] = pageNumber;

        var userList = SortResult(sortOrder);

        return View(userList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I want to know is there a more efficient way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

@dotnetBeginner Hi you could use the paging list in MVC which is much more flexible than this ....